# Order by date doesn't take Month in consideration: Foreach

Tags: php, date, foreach, google-analytics-api

I want to order my results by date. Works fine but it orders my dates by number and doesn't take the month, so it displays for example :

> 1 Feb, 2 Feb, 3 Feb, 25 Jan, 26 Jan, 27 Jan, 28 Jan, 29 Jan, 30 Jan,
>   31 Jan

But I want :

> 25 Jan, 26 Jan, 27 Jan, 28 Jan, 29 Jan, 30 Jan, 31 Jan, 1 Feb, 2 Feb,
>   3 Feb

My code :

```
$ga->requestReportData($profileId,array('date'),array('visitors'), '-date'); 

foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
    echo "{period: '" . date('j M Y',strtotime($result->getDate())) . 
         "', Visites: " . $result->getVisitors() . "},\n";
}
```

**EDIT:**

It's working fine but When I want to put in a graph, it doesn't order like I want.

My graph :

```
$(function () {
// Use Morris.Area instead of Morris.Line
    Morris.Area({
        element: 'graph-area',
        padding: 10,
        behaveLikeLine: true,
        gridEnabled: false,
        gridLineColor: '#dddddd',
        axes: false,
        fillOpacity:.7,
        data: [<?php

foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
    echo "{period: '".date('j M Y',strtotime($result->getDate()))."', Visites: ".$result->getVisitors()."},\n";}     


?>],
        lineColors:['#E67A77','#79D1CF','#79D1CF'],
        xkey: 'period',
        ykeys: ['Visites'],
        labels: ['Visites'],
        pointSize: 4,
        lineWidth: 2,
        hideHover: 'auto'

    });
});
```

Comment: where is requestReportData? sorting seems to be done there.

Comment: How are you querying your data? `foreach` has no order by parameter.

Comment: I'm using Google analytics API

Comment: Please have a look to my EDIT

Answer (score 2):

Okay, i guess you're using Google Analytics API.

So, you can sort it by adding an `-` before the wanted column, like:

```
$ga->requestReportData($profileId,array('date'),array('visitors'), '-date');
```

### From the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/wiki/GAPIDocumentation):

> Dimension(s) or metric(s) to sort by. Ascending order default, precede option with '-' for descending order. Use array for combination of parameters.

Comment: Yes, i did that but feb is still first

Comment: Ok ok, its working, but my chart doesn't take it in consideration